# How do I add/subtract pointers to different sections of the heap (in C)

Tags: c

In a program I'm writing, I am implementing binary tree and linked list structures; because I don't know how many nodes I will need, I am putting them on the heap and having the program use realloc() if they need more room.

The problem is that such structures include pointers to other locations in the same structure, and because the realloc() moves the structure, I need to redo all those pointers (unless I change them to offsets, but that increases the complexity of the code and the cost of using the structure, which is far more common than the reallocations).

Now, this might not be a problem; I could just take the old pointer, subtract it from the new pointer, and add the result to each of the pointers I need to change.  However, this only works if it is possible to subtract two pointers and get the difference in their addresses (and then add that difference to another pointer to get the pointer that many bytes ahead); because I'm working on the heap, I can't guarantee that the difference of addresses will be divisible by the size of the entries, so normal pointer subtraction (which gives the number of objects in between) will introduce errors.  So how do I make it give me the difference in bytes, and work even when they are in two different sections of the heap?

Comment: You can't - you can only subtract pointers that point to elements of the same array anyway.

Comment: Two things to look at in c99 are the `ptrdiff_t` and `uintptr_t` which can always be used to reference a pointer and the difference between two pointers. A uintptr_t also does arithmetic addition and subtraction rather than pointer arithmetic (which is based on the size of the object pointed to).

Comment: It sounds like you're allocating all of your nodes in a single large allocation, which may be more efficient but is not very flexible.  Why don't you just allocate and deallocate each node individually with `malloc` and `free`?

Comment: For reference, one of the useful side effects of how linked lists and trees work, is that *you don't need to move nodes*.  Don't realloc the whole list; just grab enough memory for another node and point an existing node's `next`/`child` pointer at it.

Comment: You can indeed subtract two pointers, get the difference, then add that difference to a third pointer to get a fourth that sort of "mirrors" the second.  You just gotta understand pointer arithmetic (and pointer casts).  Study it well, and assume nothing.

Comment: @H2CO3: Right. To be precise, you *can* subtract pointers to unrelated objects, but the behavior of doing so is undefined. (It's likely to "work", which is actually the worst possible outcome since it can hide bugs.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Darn it, I was going to mention UB (I always do), looks like I forgot it. Thanks for including that. So now in bold italics: ***it is undefined behavior.***

Comment: @Will: `ptrdiff_t` is just the integer type that's the result of subtracting two pointers -- but subtracting two pointers that don't point to the same object or into (or just past the end of) the same array still has undefined behavior. Converting to `uintptr_t` doesn't help; `(uintptr_t)ptr1 - (uintptr_t)ptr0` doesn't invoke UB, but it doesn't necessarily yield a meaningful result (I've actually worked on systems where it doesn't). But in fact the OP probably doesn't need to use `realloc()` at all.

Comment: Are you carving out multiple nodes from a single `malloc`ed or `realloc`ed chunk of memory? The usual approach is a single `malloc` for each node.

Answer (score 3):

To get the difference between two pointers in bytes, cast them to `char *`:

```
(char *) ptrA - (char *) ptrB;
```

However, if you'd like to implement a binary tree or linked list with all nodes sharing the same block of memory, consider using an array of structs instead, with the pointers being replaced by array indices.  The primary advantage of using pointers for a linked list or tree, rather than an array of structs, is that you can add or remove nodes individually without reallocating memory or moving other nodes around, but by making the nodes share the same array, you're negating this advantage.

Answer (score 2):

The best way would indeed be to `malloc()` a new chunk for every node you have. But this might have some overhead for the internal management of the memory, so if you have lots of them, it might be useful to indeed allocate space fore more nodes at once.

If you need to realloc then, you should go another way:

```
1. Calculate the offset within your memory block: `ofs = ptrX - start`
2. Add this offset to the new address returned by `realloc()`.
```

This way, you always stay inside the area you allocated and don't have strange heap pointer differences with nearly no meaning.

Comment: I was about to suggest this.  My only caution is that one should probably compute `ofs` _before_ calling `realloc`.  I fear that, otherwise, it will no longer necessarily be true that `ptrX` and `start` point to elements in the same array, for they may not point into _any_ array anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In fact ,you can use `malloc` or `calloc` to get memory for each node.

So you only need to remeber the address of tree's root node.

In this way, you never need `realloc` memeory for the whole tree . The address of each node also never change . :)